# Set cursor to the beginning inside UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cursor, uitextview

```
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
```

This has no effect on where the cursor is placed.

I then used a breakpoint and typed in `po textView.selectedRange` in the debugger.

The result was:

> (lldb) property 'selectedRange' not found on object of type
>   'UITextView *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since UITextView inherits from UIResponder. So, you can call the -becomeFirstResponder method on your text view, which will cause it to become the first responder and begin editing:

```
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

After that, you can selectedRange of UITextView.

```
    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
```

## Steps

1. Added the UITextView in Story board view controller.
2. Added the UITextView delegate in View controller.

   ```
   @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
   ```
3. Assign the property to text view.

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
   ```
4. And selected the text range in textview.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

           [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
           [self.textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you have text in the UITextView?

Comment: So what I actually wanted was that if I click on the UITextView, this action should take place, the `becomeFirstResponder` method wasn't working in `textViewDidBeginEditing`, so I masked the `textView` with a button in whose `touchUpInside` I put `[self.textView becomeFirstResponder]`, this worked